# WordPress issue with undefined constant on CHILD_THEME_VERSION

Tags: php, wordpress, undefined, constants

Odd situation with a script to produce a masonry effect on my client's WP blog. All of a sudden, I'm getting this error on all pages that use the masonry script:

```
 Warning: Use of undefined constant CHILD_THEME_VERSION - assumed 'CHILD_THEME_VERSION' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP) in /home/customer/www/writtenpalette.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/writpall/masonry.php on line 12
```

So it's part of this PHP code right near the bottom:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'jmd_masonry_script' );
function jmd_masonry_script() {
    if (is_home() || is_archive()) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'masonry-init', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/masonry-init.js' , array( 'jquery-masonry' ), '1.0', true );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'masonry-styles', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style-masonry.css', array(), CHILD_THEME_VERSION );  
    }
}
```

Any idea how to correct this?

Comment: is `CHILD_THEME_VERSION` defined anywhere? if you type `'CHILD_THEME_VERSION'` with quotes, does the error go away, and does everything work?

Comment: Yea, that was the fix. Quite odd, because I've been running this script for years and never had this problem until today.

Answer (score 0):

That is using a PHP constant.

CHILD_THEME_VERSION is not defined as you can tell from the error message.

However, there are a few ways to fix this.

Per the - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

version is option and by default false.

So below we have these options on how to fix it.

- Make the constant yourself with a value of like 1.0.
- Replace it with a version in quotes
- Set it to false
- Set it to null
- Just remove it